# Use Multifunctionbuttons from a Tablet in MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I bought a tablet that has 4 additional function buttons: f1, f2, f3 and f4.
I would like to assign an event to these buttons so that they perform a function within my app when pressed.
Unfortunately, I do not know how to access such buttons.

I've been reading up on the Android documentation for watches, because you do a lot with the buttons there. Unfortunately, I didn't find anything useful for MAUI in there.

Comment: you're going to have to figure out how these buttons work with native Android before you can answer the question for MAUI.  They may just use macros assigned by some system app, or they may rely on a custom API provided by the manufacturer.  Or something else entirely.

Comment: And you wont find. You are looking for KeyEvents (Android) and KeyCommands (IOS). Search the same question, but for Xamarin, so you get the basic idea what you need to do.

Comment: @Jason thanks for the info. It is a FuturePad FPZ08-A. I'll have a look at the manufacturer's website and see what I can find.